# How to apply font properties (name, size, bold, etc...) to all Objets by creating a style using Bitmap Style Designer

Tags: delphi, fonts, delphi-xe8, vcl-styles

Delphi XE8 provides the "Bitmap Style Designer" tool ('Tools > Bitmap Style Designer') which can be used to edit and create styles. Changing graphics and COLORS for buttons, checkboxes and labels works and looks pretty fly. But when the style is applied the FONT don’t change.

How can I change the Font Settings? To be more precise: What can I do to let the font settings take effect on my application?

This problem was already detected in other questions but it was not solved, I want to know if someone found an efficient solution.

Relative questions:

Change Font in Bitmap Style Designer [question1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28169679).

Changing font of TActionMainMenuBar when using Vcl styles [question2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13154517).

*Edit: I found the issue in Embarcadero QI: https://quality.embarcadero.com/browse/RSP-16463 please vote it if you think that is necesary that this function work properly